# syntax error in python 3.4

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, try-except

I am getting a syntax error when I use except: even for simple try: a=0 except: statement

```
 try :
a=0
print(a + 2)
except :
```

And the error is

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Is that really how you indented your code? Is the `except:` block really empty?

Comment: I'll take a guess: You don't have anything after your `except`. `except` requires an indented block after it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has indentations errors. It should be like:

```
try:
   a = 0
   print (a+2)
except:
   #do something
```

Comment: thanks it works..i had downloaded mechanize to try some scrapping ..on python3.4. I did change as urllib2 is not available on 3 version. now I am getting zipimport.ZipImportError: bad local file header in C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mechanize-0.2.5-py3.4.egg
>>>